# Flutter custom widget in ListView causing lag

Tags: dart, flutter

**main.dart class**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return MyCustomStatefulWidget(
        "Text = $index",
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Things work fine, but if I have say 1000 items in my list, then I can see the stuttering animations when `ListView` scrolls, and `MyCustomStatefulWidget`'s `dispose()` method gets called for 990 items (which were not there on the screen). How to do this in a better way?

In other words, I can ask ***Is there any way to reuse/recycle my previous Widget*** so that it doesn't get build up for 1000 items.

Here is the code for my `StatefulWidget` class, however for simplicity, I am using plain `Text` here. But in real world, I doing other stuff which needs it to be `StatefulWidget`

---

**MyCustomStatefulWidget class**

```
class MyCustomStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyCustomStatefulWidget(this.title);

  @override
  _MyCustomStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyCustomStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyCustomStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyCustomStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(widget.title);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("dispose");
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: no, there is no such way - but creating `Widget`s in dart is cheap so....

Comment: btw i run your code (without `print("dispose");` of course) and i dont see any difference in the performance between returning `MyCustomStatefulWidget` or `Text` from the builder

Comment: @pskink including/excluding `dispose()` won't have any effect. Like in Android development, whether you override activity lifecycle methods like `onStart()`, `onPause()`, `onDestroy()` won't make any difference. Their work is just to notify you the change took place, do you wanna do some sort of work there. So, by putting `dispose()` there, you are getting to know if this method actually got called, and the reason. I can explain that in much more detail if you wanna put this conversation in a chat. I really appreciate your help though. You've answered my previous questions too. I do remember.

Comment: i mean `print("dispose");` slows down the overral performance - thats why i said i run your code **with** overriden `dispose` method but **without** `print` function

Comment: and the fact you are using `StatfulWidget` (instead of `StatelessWidget` like `Text`) does not make any significant impact on performance: for example `ExpansionTile` is `StatfulWidget` too and you could try it in your `ListView.builder` to see if it slow or not

Comment: Thanks I misunderstood you, I thought you told to remove `dispose()` and then run the code. I'll give `ExpansionTile` a try and will let you know the performance, Thank you again :) You've been very helpful.

Comment: After using `ExpansionTile` I did find that its `dispose()` method is getting called every time too like mine widget. So, seems like there is nothing wrong in my implementation. Both are having same fps (tested in my emulator).  I really really pay thanks to you pskink for your hints and suggestion. You are really awesome dude :) Hope to see you again when I post a new question.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

ListView children should be automatically rebuilt when off-screen. If child widgets persists, you can disable keeping items alive by [disabling AutomaticKeepAlive](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html#destruction-mitigation)

```dart
ListView(
  children: [...],
  addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
)
```